# Separate Product Image and product gallery - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

For single product page I would like to have some changes..

I add this function in function.php: add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 10 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );

And its separated but its possible to have product image static (no slider) and product gallery (thumbnails) as a slider, just normally. So product image has a different function then product gallery..

If its possible which code I have to use? or plugin...

Thnx